# Is there a way to plot the real-time movement of the labels/ bid-ask buttons/DOM on Tradingview?

Tags: pine-script, trading

I'm very much a newbie in programing, but I'm willing to learn anything, to solve this:

Basically TW has a function of showing the latest best bid/ask. However, it has no way of accessing historical data.
https://www.tradingview.com/blog/en/display-bid-ask-labels-and-levels-19761/

Question: can there be an indicator with the current bid/ask price as an input? Basic idea is to create an indicator that would plot a chart which moves the same way bid or ask moves. Such indicator would differ from bid/ask buttons since it "records" and plots the prior bid ask changes over time. Of course, once one reloads the page, the recorded data would probably disappear.

Any help welcomed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TradingView does not expose bid/ask quotes to Pine, so what you're asking is currently not possible I'm afraid.